# Extenject - NullReferenceException when second time inject

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

I'm new at Zenject(Extenject).

My dev environment: Win10, Unity2020, Extenject 9.2.0

Here is my question:

**In installer bind the class**

`Container.Bind<AccountInfo>().AsCached();`

**Inject it at classA**

```
private AccountInfo accountInfo;             

[Inject]
private void Init(GameSetup _gameSetup, AccountInfo _accountInfo)
{
    this.gameSetup = _gameSetup; 
    this.accountInfo = _accountInfo;
}

accountInfo.address = "xxx'; // works fine
```

**Then inject AccountInfo to classB**

```
private AccountInfo accountInfo;      
        
[Inject]
private void Init(AccountInfo _accountInfo)
{
    this.accountInfo = _accountInfo;
}

accountInfo.address = "xxx'; //NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

**Why accountInfo changed to null? AsCached() dosen't work? Or something worng else?**

**Help please~~ Thank you!**

Here is my code:

**Installer**
[image]

**"ClassA" inject GameSetup, and create instance, works fine**
[image]

**"ClassB" inject GameSetup, Error: null object**
[image]

**"ClassB" Creator, I'm trying use container.Instantiate() to create it**
[image]

---

---update---
**gameSetup still Null Object**
[image]

Comment: did you bind `classB` to the container¿?. I would check that and check if the `[Inject]` runs in the `classB` with a breakpoint in the line `this.accountInfo = _accountInfo;`

Comment: Nope, I didn't bind classB to the container. I'll have a try. Thank you!

Comment: Wait! ClassA also did not bind to the container. Why it works fine?  ClassA is a consumer , it does not need  to bind.

Comment: Can you provide full code for classA and classB? It is not clear when `accountInfo.address = "xxx';` is called. Could it be called before `Init`? In constructor maybe.

Comment: Sure, I just updated.

Comment: Please add code, errors, and data as **text** ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) can't be copy-&-pasted for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format are much, *much* better than code/errors/data as an image, which are somewhat better than nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cases, when injection will not work properly in your code.

1. The code, that uses injected object is executed before `Init`. For example if this code is placed in the construcor.
2. You create your GameObject/Component in runtime whithout using `IInstantiator`. While you use Znject you always should use `IInstantiator` to create objects. To do it you should inject `IInstantiator` to the object, that creates another objects. `IItstantiator` is always binded in the container by default, so you don't have to bind it manually. For example:

```cs
public class Creator : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _somePrefab;

    private IInstantiator _instantiator;

    [Inject]
    public void Initialize(IInstantiator instantiator) {
        _instantiator = instantiator;
    }

    private void Start() {

        // example of creating components
        var gameObj = new GameObject(); // new empty gameobjects can be created without IInstantiator
        _instantiator.InstantiateComponent<YourComponentClass>(gameObj);

        // example of instantiating prefab
        var prefabInstance = _instantiator.InstantiatePrefab(_somePrefab);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!
1. Nope, I didn't use injected object in ClassB's construcor.
2. ClassB is Non-MonoBehaviour. Maybe I can use Container.Instantiate<T>() ? 
Like this:
Container.Instantiate<ClassB>(); //In other class where I create ClassB's instance.
But I can't get the Container object.

Comment: Does ClassB inherit `MonoBehaviour`? If it is, so there is no way to do this. Moreover it is bad practice to use constructors with MonoBehaviours.  But methods marked with `[Inject]` are called before `Awake()`, so you can place your initialisation logic inside `Awake()`. If ClassB is a regular C# class, that doesn't inherit `MonoBehaviour`, `Component` or other classes managed by Unity, so you can use constructor injection. To do this you don’t need to mark any method with `[Inject]`. Just add `AccountInfo` to the constructor arguments. And you still need create instances with `IInstantiator`

Comment: ---update---
[Inject]private DiContainer Container;  //Dose not work, null object.

Comment: "Does ClassB inherit MonoBehaviour?"  No.

Comment: So add `AccountInfo` parameter to the constructor, and create instance like this: `var instanceOfClassB = instantiator.Instantiate<ClassB>();`

Comment: Really thanks!~  let me have a try.  By the way. I was edited this question, added my code.

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert but I think that passing `IInstantiator` or the container around is not a good practice. If you need to create injected instances at runtime, then you need a Factory.
From the [documentation](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject)

1.- Best practice with DI is to only reference the container in the composition root "layer"

Note that factories are part of this layer and the container can be referenced there (which is necessary to create objects at runtime).

2.- "When instantiating objects directly, you can either use DiContainer or you can use IInstantiator, which DiContainer inherits from. However, note that injecting the DiContainer is usually a sign of bad practice, since there is almost always a better way to design your code such that you don't need to reference DiContainer directly".

3.- "Once again, best practice with dependency injection is to only reference the DiContainer in the "composition root layer""